# How to make my app does't hang during the animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, animation

I made a hybrid app. One page contains three animated (in css) pictures. They just have to slide in. Everything works fine as I want it to work but the problem is that these photos hang every single time (I think because they have quite good quality) and run actually like 0.5s before the end so we miss whole animation. Is there any cordova plugin or something which would load my pictures and start the animation only when they are ready?
I use jquery to add animations to every single picture because I don't want them to slide at the same time. Here is how I did it:

```
setTimeout( function(){
$('#photo_one').addClass('animated my_animation');
}, 500)
setTimeout( function(){
$('#photo_two').addClass('animated my_animation');
}, 1000)
setTimeout( function(){
$('#photo_three').addClass('animated my_animation');
}, 1500)
```

**EDIT** My animation:

```
 .my_animation{
  -webkit-animation-name: my_animation;
  animation-name: my_animation;
  opacity: 1!important;
}

@keyframes my_animation{
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: what does `.animated` and `.my_animation` do?

Comment: That adds animation called "my_animation" to my object.

Comment: no, I mean what do those classes do - what animation code do those classes apply to the element?

Comment: It's just jquery <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>. I saw it once in internet and works fine. I hope I understood your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can load all and then change the `zIndex` to bring forward the next image:

```
document.getElementById("img1").style.zIndex = "1";
```

Comment: But on this page I have actually only these three pictures (on which you can click) and background. Nothing else.